# Not Between clause in MDX query

Tags: mdx, ssas-2008, ssas-2012

I have applied between clause on measure by using following line:

```
 [Measures].[Expense Count] < 500 and [Measures].[Expense Count] > 100
```

Which translate into `[Measures].[Expense Count] should be between 100  and 500`

How can I say [Measures].[Expense Count] should **NOT** be between 100  and 500

Do we have anything like **not between** clause in MDX query?

Comment: Doesn't your example query do exactly what you want? `< 69901 AND > 68900` should return everything not between 68801 and 68900. Play with the comparators to get the range you like.

Comment: @zwippie: The example I used was wrong. Now I have corrected the condition. [Measures].[Expense Count] < 500 and [Measures].[Expense Count] > 100 -- get me 200 records. Changing to [Measures].[Expense Count] < 100 and [Measures].[Expense Count] > 500 -- returns 0 record as a value cannot be less than 100 and greater than 500 at the same time.

Comment: Then use `OR` in stead of `AND`.

Comment: @zwippie : OR condition works & Now i am thinking why I asked such silly question ? Thank you for the help. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

you can try something like this for `NOT BETWEEN`

```
[Measures].[Expense Count] > 500 OR [Measures].[Expense Count] < 100
```

Answer (score 0):

Logically the same as the previous answer is the following:

```
NOT ([Measures].[Expense Count] > 500 AND [Measures].[Expense Count] < 100)
```